# Crawl news website from rss with scrapy

Tags: python, django, scrapy, rss

I want to read some news websites rss feeds for example nytimes.com rss:

```
<item>
    <title>
        White House Signals Acceptance of Russia Sanctions Bill
    </title>
    <link>
        https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/23/us/politics/trump-russia-
        sanctions.html?partner=rss&emc=rss
    </link>
    <pubDate>Sun, 23 Jul 2017 23:26:41 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
    <title>
        News Analysis: For Trump and Putin, Sanctions Are a Setback 
        Both Sought to Avoid
    </title>
    <link>
        https://www.nytimes.com/2017/07/23/world/europe/trump-putin-
        sanctions-hacking.html?partner=rss&emc=rss
    </link>
    <pubDate>Mon, 24 Jul 2017 00:35:14 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
```

find new items that i didn't read yet, and for each item store link, title and GET link to crawl some content of it.
my question is can i use [scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html) for this purpose and if yes, how?

Comment: what you want to do can be done by an API call. Don't waste server capacity with scraping if you can use API instead. Check out the API service. https://developer.nytimes.com .

Comment: @hansTheFranz there is no api for most of the target websites :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use Scrapy for that purpose. There are couple of things you can use to build your solution:

- Start with [`XMLFeedSpider`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#xmlfeedspider) designed to parse XML feeds. There's a simple example in the link provided.
- To follow links to individual articles, extract some data from it and add it to data extracted from XML feed, use concept of [requests chaining](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-callback-arguments).
- You didn't specify how should *items that I didn't read yet* be realized. If you mean not returning items already scraped in some previous runs, you could use [`scrapy-deltafetch`](https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-deltafetch) package.

Now you just need to put these pieces together.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm actually new in Scrappy. i don't know how run process to check rss feeds all the time for new items. does scrappy handle new items itself? i updated my question with <pubDate> tag

Comment: Scrapy itself doesn't handle scraping only new items, that's what you have to implement or, use some already available component like `scrapy-deltafetch`. If, in your case, you want to implement the logic with regards to the `pubDate` attribute, you would have to be able to get the date and time of when you spider last started. I, for example, in one project store spider `stats` in InfluxDB so I can read them in subsequent runs.